# Save a custom field value via ajax in WooCommerce Admin product list

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I have written a code that is responsible for displaying an input that receives a number and stores it in the WooCommerce section. This number is for me to know how many of each product I should buy. Now my problem is that I cannot save the information. This is my code

```
function custom_order_column_header($columns) {
    $columns['order'] = 'Order?';
    return $columns;
}
add_filter('manage_edit-product_columns', 'custom_order_column_header');


function custom_order_column_data($column, $post_id) {
    if ($column === 'order') {
        $purchase_quantity = get_post_meta($post_id, '_purchase_quantity', true);
        echo '<input type="number" name="purchase_quantity[' . $post_id . ']" value="' . esc_attr($purchase_quantity) . '">';
        echo '<button type="button" class="save-purchase-quantity button button-primary" data-product-id="' . $post_id . '">Save</button>';
    }
}
add_action('manage_product_posts_custom_column', 'custom_order_column_data', 10, 2);


function save_custom_order_column_data() {
    if (isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] === 'save_purchase_quantity') {
        $post_id = isset($_POST['product_id']) ? intval($_POST['product_id']) : 0;
        $purchase_quantity = isset($_POST['purchase_quantity']) ? sanitize_text_field($_POST['purchase_quantity']) : '';

        if ($post_id && $purchase_quantity) {
            update_post_meta($post_id, '_purchase_quantity', $purchase_quantity);
        }
    }
}
add_action('wp_ajax_save_purchase_quantity', 'save_custom_order_column_data');


function enqueue_custom_js() {
    ?>
    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            $('.save-purchase-quantity').on('click', function() {
                let productId = $(this).data('product-id');
                let purchaseQuantity = $('input[name="purchase_quantity[' + productId + ']"]').val();

                $.ajax({
                    url: ajaxurl,
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: {
                        action: 'save_purchase_quantity',
                        product_id: productId,
                        purchase_quantity: purchaseQuantity,
                    },
                    success: function(response) {
                        // Update the column after successful save if needed
                        console.log('Purchase Quantity saved successfully');
                    },
                    error: function(error) {
                        console.error('Error saving Purchase Quantity');
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
    <?php
}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_custom_js');
```

Using the code above, I just want to enter the Order? column. I should set the value of the field that I made specifically so that I don't have to enter each product every time.

In this section, I have created the particular field that is necessary.

```
function custom_product_meta_fields() {
    global $post;

    // Add a custom "Purchase Quantity" field
    woocommerce_wp_text_input(array(
        'id' => '_purchase_quantity',
        'label' => __('Purchase Quantity', 'woocommerce'),
        'placeholder' => '',
        'desc_tip' => 'true',
        'description' => __('Enter the purchase quantity for this product.', 'woocommerce'),
        'value' => get_post_meta($post->ID, '_purchase_quantity', true),
    ));
}
add_action('woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', 'custom_product_meta_fields');


function save_custom_product_meta_fields($post_id) {
    $purchase_quantity = isset($_POST['_purchase_quantity']) ? sanitize_text_field($_POST['_purchase_quantity']) : '';
    update_post_meta($post_id, '_purchase_quantity', $purchase_quantity);
}
add_action('woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'save_custom_product_meta_fields');
```

Let me remind you that when I enter a product and enter a number, the number will be displayed in the Order column after updating, but I don't want to open the products one by one, but I want to save with the same save button that I have in the Order column.

I went to several solutions but did not get an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple mistakes and missing things in your code.

Also, as WooCommerce is migrating data progressively to custom tables, you should avoid using WordPress get_post_meta(), add_post_meta(), update_post_meta() and delete_post_meta() functions.

Use the following revisited code instead:

```php
add_filter('manage_edit-product_columns', 'admin_product_purchase_quantity_column');
function admin_product_purchase_quantity_column($columns) {
    $columns['order'] = 'Order?';
    return $columns;
}

add_action('manage_product_posts_custom_column', 'admin_product_purchase_quantity_column_content', 10, 2);
function admin_product_purchase_quantity_column_content($column, $post_id) {
    if ($column === 'order') {
        global $product;

        $qty = esc_attr($product->get_meta('_purchase_quantity'));

        echo '<input type="number" name="purchase_qty-'.$post_id.'" value="'.$qty.'" style="width:100px">
        <button type="button" class="update-qty button button-primary" data-id="'.$post_id.'">Update</button>
        <span class="message-'.$post_id.'" style="display:none"></span>';
    }
}

add_action('wp_ajax_save_purchase_quantity', 'ajax_save_purchase_qty');
function ajax_save_purchase_qty() {
    if (isset($_POST['product_id']) && isset($_POST['purchase_qty'])) {
        $product = wc_get_product(intval($_POST['product_id']));

        $product->update_meta_data('_purchase_quantity', intval($_POST['purchase_qty']));
        echo $product->save(); // We return the product Id when saved, as a response.
    }
    wp_die(); // Exit silently (Always at the end to avoid an Error 500)
}

add_action('admin_footer', 'save_purchase_qty_js');
function save_purchase_qty_js() {
    global $pagenow, $typenow;

    if( 'edit.php' === $pagenow && 'product' === $typenow ) :
    ?>
    <script id="save-purchase-qty" type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(function($) {
            $('body').on('click', 'button.update-qty', function() {
                const productID   = $(this).data('id'),
                      purchaseQty = $('input[name=purchase_qty-'+productID+']').val();
                        console.log(productID);
                $.ajax({
                    url:  '<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ); ?>',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: {
                        'action':       'save_purchase_quantity',
                        'product_id':   productID,
                        'purchase_qty': purchaseQty,
                    },
                    success: function(response) {
                        if ( response > 0 ) {
                            $('.message-'+response).html(' Updated').css('color','green').fadeIn().delay(1500).fadeOut();
                        }
                        console.log(response);
                    },
                    error: function(error) {
                        $('.message-'+productID).html(' Error').css('color','green').fadeIn().delay(1500).fadeOut();
                        console.log(error);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
    <?php
    endif;
}

add_action('woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', 'admin_product_purchase_quantity_field');
function admin_product_purchase_quantity_field() {
    global $product_object;

    // Add a custom "Purchase Quantity" field
    woocommerce_wp_text_input( array(
        'id'            => '_purchase_quantity',
        'type'          => 'number',
        'label'         => __('Purchase Quantity', 'woocommerce'),
        'placeholder'   => '',
        'desc_tip'      => 'true',
        'description'   => __('Enter the purchase quantity for this product.', 'woocommerce'),
    ));
}

add_action('woocommerce_admin_process_product_object', 'save_product_purchase_quantity_field_value');
function save_product_purchase_quantity_field_value($product) {
    $meta_value = isset($_POST['_purchase_quantity']) ? intval($_POST['_purchase_quantity']) : '';
    $product->update_meta_data('_purchase_quantity', $meta_value);
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and works.