# Custom input fields to update stock quantity in WooCommerce Admin Product list

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

In WooCommerce Admin Product list, I have added an input box with a simple button, for each product, that should update the stock quantity. For instance, if I input '5' and then click on the 'Refresh' button, I've noticed that nothing happens, and the product stock quantity is not updated.

Is there a specific term I should be using for the updating process?

Need to mention, that I use this code in the functions.php file.

```
add_action( 'manage_product_posts_custom_column', 'custom_product_is_in_stock_column_content', 10, 2 );
function custom_product_is_in_stock_column_content( $column, $product_id ) {
    switch ( $column ) {
        case 'is_in_stock':
            echo '<div class="stock-box">';
            echo '<form method="post">';
            echo '<input type="number" class="stock-input" name="stock_value" value="' . ( get_post_meta( $product_id, '_stock_status', true ) == 'instock' ? 1 : 0 ) . '" min="0">';
            echo '<button type="submit" class="stock-button" name="update_stock">&#8635;</button>';
            echo '</form>';
            echo '</div>';
            break;
    }
}

add_action( 'admin_post_update_stock', 'update_product_stock' );
function update_product_stock() {
    if ( isset( $_POST['stock_value'] ) && isset( $_POST['update_stock'] ) ) {
        $stock_value = intval( $_POST['stock_value'] );
        $product_id = isset( $_POST['post_ID'] ) ? intval( $_POST['post_ID'] ) : 0;

        if ( $product_id > 0 ) {
            $new_status = $stock_value > 0 ? 'instock' : 'outofstock';
            wc_update_product_stock_status( $product_id, $new_status );
        }
    }

    wp_safe_redirect( admin_url( 'edit.php?post_type=product' ) );
    exit;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are making a confusion between the product stock status and the product stock quantity.

Now, this feature requires jQuery / JavaScript / Ajax, to be able to update the product stock quantity, from those custom input fields.

The code:

```php
// Add input fields to stock status column// change default stock
add_filter('woocommerce_admin_stock_html', 'filter_woocommerce_admin_stock_html', 10, 2 );
function filter_woocommerce_admin_stock_html($stock_html, $product) {
    if ( $product->managing_stock() ) {
        return '';
    }
    return $stock_html;
}

// Add input fields to stock status column
add_action( 'manage_product_posts_custom_column', 'product_stock_quantity_column_content', 10, 2 );
function product_stock_quantity_column_content( $column, $product_id ) {
    if ( $column === 'is_in_stock' ) {
        global $product;

        if ( $product->managing_stock() ) {
            $stock_html = sprintf('<div style="margin-bottom:5px;width:120px">
            <input type="number" name="stock_qty-%d" value="%d" style="width:80px">
            <button type="button" class="update-qty button button-primary" data-id="%d">&#8635;</button>
            </div><div class="stock-%d">', 
            $product_id, $product->get_stock_quantity('edit'), $product_id, $product_id, $product_id);

            if ( $product->is_on_backorder() ) {
                $stock_html .= '<mark class="onbackorder">' . __( 'On backorder', 'woocommerce' ) . '</mark>';
            } elseif ( $product->is_in_stock() ) {
                $stock_html .= '<mark class="instock">' . __( 'In stock', 'woocommerce' ) . '</mark>';
            } else {
                $stock_html .= '<mark class="outofstock">' . __( 'Out of stock', 'woocommerce' ) . '</mark>';
            }
            echo $stock_html .' (' . wc_stock_amount( $product->get_stock_quantity() ) . ')</div>';
        }
    }     
}

// WP Admin Ajax receiver
add_action('wp_ajax_update_stock_quantity', 'update_stock_quantity_ajax');
function update_stock_quantity_ajax() {
    if (isset($_POST['product_id']) && isset($_POST['update_qty'])) {
        $product = wc_get_product(intval($_POST['product_id']));

        $product->set_stock_quantity(intval($_POST['update_qty']));
        $id = $product->save();

        if ( $product->is_on_backorder() ) {
            $stock_html = '<mark class="onbackorder">' . __( 'On backorder', 'woocommerce' ) . '</mark>';
        } elseif ( $product->is_in_stock() ) {
            $stock_html = '<mark class="instock">' . __( 'In stock', 'woocommerce' ) . '</mark>';
        } else {
            $stock_html = '<mark class="outofstock">' . __( 'Out of stock', 'woocommerce' ) . '</mark>';
        }
        $stock_html .= ' (' . wc_stock_amount( $product->get_stock_quantity() ) . ')';

        echo $stock_html;
    }
    wp_die(); // Exit silently (Always at the end to avoid an Error 500)
}

// jQuery Ajax
add_action('admin_footer', 'update_stock_quantity_js');
function update_stock_quantity_js() {
    global $pagenow, $typenow;

    if( 'edit.php' === $pagenow && 'product' === $typenow ) :
    ?>
    <script id="update-stock-qty" type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(function($) {
            $('body').on('click', 'button.update-qty', function() {
                const productID = $(this).data('id'),
                      updateQty = $('input[name=stock_qty-'+productID+']').val();
                $.ajax({
                    url:  '<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ); ?>',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: {
                        'action':     'update_stock_quantity',
                        'product_id': productID,
                        'update_qty': updateQty,
                    },
                    success: function(response) {
                        if ( response ) {
                            const message = '<div class="message-'+productID+'">Success !</div>';
                            $('.stock-'+productID).html(response).after();
                            $('.stock-'+productID).prepend(message);
                            setTimeout(function(){
                                $('.message-'+productID).remove();
                            }, 5000);
                        }
                    },
                    error: function(error) {
                        if ( error ) {
                            const message = '<div class="message-'+productID+'">Error !</div>';
                            $('.stock-'+productID).prepend(message);
                            setTimeout(function(){
                                $('.message-'+productID).remove();
                            }, 5000);
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
    <?php
    endif;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and works.

Related: [Save a custom field value via ajax in WooCommerce Admin product list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76842076/save-a-custom-field-value-via-ajax-in-woocommerce-admin-product-list/76842752#76842752)

Comment: That's awesome, is working. The only thing that it is bothering now, is that it won't update the actual stock (view only) only if I refresh the page. How can this be done?

Comment: I made some changes, like increasing the delay at `5000`, I made this in case I took my eyes off the screen and didn't see the message, to stay there a bit longer.

Let me know if what you'll try is refreshing  the displayed stock quantity.

Comment: Awesome. It has a few seconds after it updates the quantity that is displayed, but it nothing more or less then just perfect! I'm really thankful for your help and time.

Comment: How to make so after using the update button, it'll show below a "updated" or "failed" message for 5 seconds?

Comment: @GFT I have updated my code (the last function).

Comment: Awesome! This helps me keep an eye on what product I just updated.

Comment: You can always increase the delay from 5000 to whatever value in milliseconds, or even remove both setTimeout functions.

Comment: Would it be possible to make the button rotate like it's loading ?

Comment: Use [font awesome 5 icons](https://fontawesome.com/v5/search) (included in WooCommerce)

Comment: I included the loading icon, it will change from the original button into an empty box, but the loading icon won't load, and I imported the library from awesome font.

Comment: How can i show the current code? Edit the original one, post is from pastebin?

Comment: Maybe ask a new question.