# Font Awesome loading icon doesn't show up in WooCommerce Admin list

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, woocommerce, font-awesome

Based on [Custom input fields to update stock quantity in WooCommerce Admin Product list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76944145/custom-input-fields-to-update-stock-quantity-in-woocommerce-admin-product-list/76945156#76945156) previous answer to one of my questions.

The following code adds a custom button for the quantity column that updates the quantity when the button is pressed and refreshes the current quantity. Tried to add a loading spinner after pressing the button, but it won't load.

Here is the code from `functions.php` file:

```
// Add input fields to stock status column// change default stock
add_filter('woocommerce_admin_stock_html', 'filter_woocommerce_admin_stock_html', 10, 2 );
function filter_woocommerce_admin_stock_html($stock_html, $product) {
    if ( $product->managing_stock() ) {
        return '';
    }
    return $stock_html;
}

// Add input fields to stock status column
add_action( 'manage_product_posts_custom_column', 'product_stock_quantity_column_content', 10, 2 );
function product_stock_quantity_column_content( $column, $product_id ) {
    if ( $column === 'is_in_stock' ) {
        global $product;

        if ( $product->managing_stock() ) {
            $stock_html = sprintf('<div style="margin-bottom:5px;width:120px">
            <input type="text" name="stock_qty-%d" value="%d" style="width:35px; padding: 5px; text-align: center; height: 30px;" inputmode="numeric">
            <button type="button" class="update-qty button button-primary" data-id="%d">&#8635;</button>
            </div><div class="stock-%d">', 
            $product_id, $product->get_stock_quantity('edit'), $product_id, $product_id, $product_id);

            if ( $product->is_on_backorder() ) {
                $stock_html .= '<mark class="onbackorder">' . __( 'On backorder', 'woocommerce' ) . '</mark>';
            } elseif ( $product->is_in_stock() ) {
                $stock_html .= '<mark class="instock">' . __( 'In stock', 'woocommerce' ) . '</mark>';
            } else {
                $stock_html .= '<mark class="outofstock">' . __( 'Out of stock', 'woocommerce' ) . '</mark>';
            }
            echo $stock_html .' (' . wc_stock_amount( $product->get_stock_quantity() ) . ')</div>';
        }
    }     
}

// WP Admin Ajax receiver
add_action('wp_ajax_update_stock_quantity', 'update_stock_quantity_ajax');
function update_stock_quantity_ajax() {
    if (isset($_POST['product_id']) && isset($_POST['update_qty'])) {
        $product = wc_get_product(intval($_POST['product_id']));

        $product->set_stock_quantity(intval($_POST['update_qty']));
        $id = $product->save();

        if ( $product->is_on_backorder() ) {
            $stock_html = '<mark class="onbackorder">' . __( 'On backorder', 'woocommerce' ) . '</mark>';
        } elseif ( $product->is_in_stock() ) {
            $stock_html = '<mark class="instock">' . __( 'In stock', 'woocommerce' ) . '</mark>';
        } else {
            $stock_html = '<mark class="outofstock">' . __( 'Out of stock', 'woocommerce' ) . '</mark>';
        }
        $stock_html .= ' (' . wc_stock_amount( $product->get_stock_quantity() ) . ')';

        echo $stock_html;
    }
    wp_die(); // Exit silently (Always at the end to avoid an Error 500)
}

// jQuery Ajax
add_action('admin_footer', 'update_stock_quantity_js');
function update_stock_quantity_js() {
    global $pagenow, $typenow;

    if( 'edit.php' === $pagenow && 'product' === $typenow ) :
    ?>
    <script id="update-stock-qty" type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(function($) {
            $('body').on('click', 'button.update-qty', function() {
                const productID = $(this).data('id'),
                      updateQty = $('input[name=stock_qty-'+productID+']').val();
            
                // Add spinner icon to the button
                $(this).html('<i class="fa-solid fa-spinner fa-spin"></i>');
            
                $.ajax({
                    url:  '<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ); ?>',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: {
                        'action':     'update_stock_quantity',
                        'product_id': productID,
                        'update_qty': updateQty,
                    },
                    success: function(response) {
                        if ( response ) {
                            const message = '<div class="message-'+productID+'">Success !</div>';
                            $('.stock-'+productID).html(response).after();
                            $('.stock-'+productID).prepend(message);
                            setTimeout(function(){
                                $('.message-'+productID).remove();
                            }, 5000);
                        }
                    },
                    error: function(error) {
                        if ( error ) {
                            const message = '<div class="message-'+productID+'">Error !</div>';
                            $('.stock-'+productID).prepend(message);
                            setTimeout(function(){
                                $('.message-'+productID).remove();
                            }, 5000);
                        }
                    },
                    complete: function() {
                        // Restore the button text (remove spinner icon)
                        $('button.update-qty').html('&#8635;');
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
    <?php
    endif;
}

function enqueue_font_awesome() {
    wp_enqueue_style('font-awesome', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.0-beta3/css/all.min.css');
}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_font_awesome');
```

Also imported the library from font awesome, right now after pressing the button, it will disappear the button and there will be an empty box.

Comment: instead of `$(this).html` try `$(this).append`

Comment: btw when you press the button, did you check using inspect mode? maybe it was added but was hidden under other elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using the correct CSS library link, and you should also restrict the function to Admin products List only. Replace your last function with:

```php
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_font_awesome_free6');
function enqueue_font_awesome_free6() {
    global $pagenow, $typenow;
    if ( $pagenow === 'edit.php' && $typenow === 'product' ) {
        wp_enqueue_style('font-awesome', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.2/css/all.min.css');
    }
}
```

Tested and works.

Here are [all the CDN correct links](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/font-awesome) for Font Awesome.

Comment: First tried with `$(this).html`, is working well.